# Configure MediaCodec with the proper MediaFormat from a raw H.264 byte buffer

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I have to decode an H.264 stream with the Android `MediaCodec` API. Problem is I don't know at this point the size of the output stream (I mean resolution of frames : 640x360? 1280x720? 1920x1080? ...). I use my own access/demuxer code to get the input stream as a `ByteBuffer` object. First step to create my `MediaCodec` is:

```
MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
```

Then, to configure it, I would like to have the proper `MediaFormat` information to configure my `MediaCodec` object fine. Currently, I do:

```
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
```

But the size is not always 1280x720 and my `MediaFormat` needs more information (on some test devices, decoder produces weird results but works fine on others). I read the doc and I saw that we can get the proper `MediaFormat` using a `MediaExtractor` and `getTrackFormat(/* idx */);`. But how can I use `MediaExtractor` with my raw `ByteBuffer` (`setDataSource(...)` can only handle file descriptors or uris)? Is there an other way to process?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I extracted SPS and PPS from my stream and provided it to the codec at the configuration step (passing by the `MediaFormat`) doing:

```
mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", bufferSPS);
mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", bufferPPS);
/*...*/
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0);
```